# Use JOIN on multiple columns multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to figure out the best way to use a `JOIN` in `MSSQL` in order to do the following:

I have two tables. One table contains technician IDs and an example of one data set would be as follows:

```
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| tagid  | techBid | techPid | techFid | techMid |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1-1001 |      12 |       0 |      11 |       6 |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I have another table that stores the names of these technicians:

```
+------+-----------+
| TTID | SHORTNAME |
+------+-----------+
|   11 | Steven    |
|   12 | Mark      |
|    6 | Pierce    |
+------+-----------+
```

If the ID of a technician in the first table is 0, there is no technician of that type for that row (types are either B, P, F, or M).

I am trying to come up with a query that will give me a result that contains all of the data from table 1 along with the shortnames from table 2 IF there is a matching ID, so the result would look something like the following:

```
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| tagid  | techBid | techPid | techFid | techMid | techBShortName | techPShortName | techFShortName | techMShortName |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 1-1001 |      12 |       0 |      11 |       6 | Mark           | NULL           | Steven         | Pierce         |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I am trying to use a `JOIN` to do this, but I cannot figure out how to join on multiple columns *multiple times* to where it would look something like

```
Select table1.tagid, table1.techBid, table1.techPid, table1.techFid, table1.techMid, table2.shortname 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 on //Dont know what to put here
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use left joins like this:

```
Select table1.tagid, table1.techBid, table1.techPid, table1.techFid, table1.techMid, 
      t2b.shortname, t2p.shortname, t2f.shortname, t2m.shortname, 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2b on table1.techBid = t2b.ttid
LEFT JOIN table2 t2p on table1.techPid = t2p.ttid
LEFT JOIN table2 t2f on table1.techFid = t2f.ttid
LEFT JOIN table2 t2m on table1.techMid = t2m.ttid
```

Answer (score 0):

you just do mutiple left join

```
select tech.techPid, techPname.SHORTNAME 
     , tech.techFid, techFname.SHORTNAME  
from tech 
left join techName as techPname 
     on tech.techPid = techPname.TTID 
left join techName as techFname 
     on tech.techFid = techFname.TTID
```

Comment: hogan was first - give him the check